# Should I bump the version of my Ruby gem for a non-semantic modification?

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, versioning

For instance, the *only* change I have made is as follows:

```
if foo.class == Hash
```

to:

```
if foo.instance_of?(Hash)
```

Would this warrant even a patch-level bump (i.e. `3.0.1` to `3.0.2`)? I'm betting "no", but want to see what others have to say.

Another thing is: I could do a patch-level bump, and push it to GitHub, but just not push it RubyGems (i.e. not bother folks with a non-meaningful update). Thoughts?

Comment: You don't have to do a release every time you make some minor adjustment. Releases are for meaningful changes. In the case of Semantic Versioning, those would be bug/security fixes, new features, major changes. Just accumulate those meaningless changes you have until they make up a meaningful release.

Comment: Not that you can push much to RubyGems these days, anyway. (=